# Xmodmap fails add clearing modifiers

Tags: xmodmap

I try to make my escape key behave as an alt modifier (and later add back the escape functionality with xcape), however I can't get xmodmap to make my escape key have this alt function.

After investigating it seems I need this

```
clear Mod1
add Mod1 = Alt_L Alt_R Escape
```

However it already fails add "clear Mod1".

I am getting this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for    operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  118 (X_SetModifierMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x17
  Serial number of failed request:  8
  Current serial number in output stream:  8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign Alt_L function to the Esc key with:
`keycode 9 = Alt_L`
Then try and see if you can assign Escape function to another key (with xcape) and, in the end, if it all works in the environment you need.